# why is access denied when I run hwinfo

Tags: hardware, permissions, password, sudo

I recently had someone install ubuntu on my laptop and something just doesn't feel right about it. I am a newbie and don't really know what I'm looking for or how to look for it. after trying to make sure none of my hardware had been swapped out and trying to find my webcam, I discovered I was set up as a user only. I asked for the superuser pass and I was told the root password but even logging in as root doesn't allow me access to hwinfo. also when I try to run anything sudo related I get 'can't resolve host sudo'. can somebody please help me with this? is this normal?

Comment: I'd suggest getting an ISO from http://ubuntu.com and reinstalling.

Comment: What exactly are you typing to get 'can't resolve host sudo'? This doesn't look right at all. Also, in Ubuntu by default there is no root password though the original user can sudo to root by typing "sudo su" and entering _their own_ password. I don't understand why the person who installed the machine knew the root password - I don't know root password to any of my machines :)

Comment: You need to open a terminal emulator and then type `sudo hwinfo`.

Comment: This is a known bug : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rescue/+bug/19553 and is caused normally, according to the bug during installation when the installer names the PC. Can you go into your terminal and type this for us. Once done post the output here?s caused normally, according to the bug during installation when the installer names the PC. Can you go into your terminal and type this for us. `cat /etc/hosts` Once done post the output here?

Comment: I typed in sudo hwinfo and it says exactly

Comment: user606723 I typed in sudo hwinfo and it says unable to resolve host blackbook and the next line says hwinfo:  command not found and then it goes back to root@blackbook:~#

Comment: and Christopher, that's a lot of output to post! I'm online with my iPhone because I don't have a consistent connection for my laptop here in my house. is there anything impaticular that you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying...
Can you post the informations on the two lines that look something like this 
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.1.1 foo

Comment: Christopher, maybe I'm missing something but I have looked thru every line and I don't see anything that says local host. almost all of them say 127.0.0.1. I would take my laptop to a hotspot and post all the output for u but now it says wireless is disabled by hardware switch...what is that?!

Comment: "Disabled by hardware switch" means you pressed Fn-F<something> where <something> is the F-key with a small picture of "wireless thingie" on it. Example: Fn-F7. Press the key combination again to enable the wireless adapter.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problems with "unable to resolve host blackbook" are not directly related to your problems with starting hwinfo. The latter, I suspect, is caused simply by the fact that hwinfo in not installed by default. At least I checked a few of my machines and none of them have hwinfo installed. I have to admit that I don't have access to a recent "vanilla" Ubuntu box - all of mine were upgraded from older Ubuntu versions. To install the program open a terminal and type the following:

```
sudo apt-get install hwinfo
```

(actually, the error message should've told you to do so). Enter *your own* password when it asks - not root's.

Then you'll be able to start it by typing

```
sudo hwinfo
```

(provided that it needs to be started as root, as somebody stated in the comments. Otherwise just type `hwinfo`)